# GO Launcher apps in HTC Sense

Tags: htc-sense, go-launcher-ex

i want to use **Go switch widget** in **htc sense launcher**. But widget list doesn't show me this one. why is that so ??

Comment: Do not GO widgets require the GO launcher?

Answer (score 3):

If you start GOWidget, there are 2 lists. Installed and not installed widgets. You can install widgets from there. If you installed the Switch widget, you can add it to your homescreen tapping on a blank space and selecting GOWidget from the list. Switch should now be listed in the Installed list. Obviously Go Launcher EX has to be installed, it cannot just be used with HTC Sense. You have to replace HTC Sense (at least the launcher) through Go Launcher EX.

Comment: i mean in sense launcher

Comment: @WebDeveloper: Then please edit your question to be more accurate.